# webview will not load pdf files on link click

Tags: android, pdf, webview, hyperlink

I have developed a web app that displays a list of pdf documents hosted on a web server. This app is embedded in a webview app for android however when I load the app on my phone, selection of a pdf link does nothing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Heres the java code:

```
package com.hellowebview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HellowebviewActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://aipnz.webs.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to load pdf you can use Google docs to load it.

```
String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
String pdf_url = "http://kronox.org/documentacion/Hello.Android.new.pdf";  

webView.loadUrl(googleDocs + pdf_url);
```

NOTE: You need android.permission.INTERNET in Manifest file

Comment: I would prefer to not use the googleDocs viewer, instead to load the PDF in an installed PDF viewer or a PDF render written into the activity code

Comment: this is a great solution if you don't wan't to bump the user out of your app to view the PDF

Comment: Great solution, seems that viewing pdf through webView is not possible with just the base url. Thanks.

Comment: This works only if pdf file size is small size otherwise this will not work. Not worked for me in case of 432 KB size pdf file. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Just create an Intent in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading method:

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if ( urlIsPDF(url)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            try{
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //user does not have a pdf viewer installed
            }
        } else {
            webview.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And then whenever a user clicks a PDF link in a page within your webview, the file will open in an external PDF app.

Comment: Works for me!. For "urlIsPDF" I used: url.endsWith(".pdf")

Comment: Just check packaging manager if intent is available before trying to open it

Answer (score 7):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            try {
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //user does not have a pdf viewer installed
            }
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will definitely help all of you,i checked it on 28 Nov 2017,its working

Comment: thanks-Works for me!. For "urlIsPDF" I used: url.endsWith(".pdf") – Alex

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution I use:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")){
            String pdfUrl = googleDocs + url;
            view.loadUrl(pdfUrl);
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

with

```
private final String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
```

Comment: nice solution...helped me a lot

Answer (score 5):

You have to override [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading) method in WebClient. I use this approach with combination of intent and Google Docs as a backup:

```
/* You might want to move this string definition somewhere else */
final String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";

WebView webView = new WebView(getContext());
//webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            /* Check if there is any application capable to process PDF file. */
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                /* If not, show PDF in Google Docs instead. */
                view.loadUrl(googleDocs + url);
            }
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

You might need to change passing the context and accessing `startActivity` method, but other than that it should run as it is.

Also note that since API 24, there are 2 `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` methods you can override. As it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484074/is-shouldoverrideurlloading-really-deprecated-what-can-i-use-instead) from @CommonsWare, it is OK to override deprecated method.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for this nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

use loadurl another overloaded methods...and write internet permission

Answer (score 0):

Sharing this answer as I tried all the above solutions but did not work for me, this is Kotlin code (not javascript)

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(object:WebViewClient() {
       override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view:WebView, url:String):Boolean {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf"))
            {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                intent.setDataAndType(android.net.Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf")
                try
                {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent)
                }
                catch (e:ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    //user does not have a pdf viewer installed
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myWebView.loadUrl(url)
            }
            return true
        }
    })
```

Comment: hello, how to do when the link of the pdf not contain .pdf extension like this
https://foulabook.com/book/downloading/401212926

Comment: If the link is not PDF that what do you want to do with it?

Comment: the above link is link to direct pdf file

Comment: You have to create custom handler for that depending in what format you are getting the data/file.