# Viewing pdf files in Android Webview from url

Tags: android, url, pdf, webview

I'm trying to open a pdf file in a Android WebView from this url:

http://bijsluiters.fagg-afmps.be/registrationSearchServlet?key=BE-TU441865&leafletType=leafletNL

When i searched for information online on how to achieve this, i found that
you need to extend the url with this in front of it: "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="

but when i do this, i can only see html like when you open the link in a browser: 
"https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://bijsluiters.fagg-afmps.be/registrationSearchServlet?key=BE-TU441865&leafletType=leafletNL"

How can i see the actual non-html content in my webview?

```
public class BijsluiterFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    //Title = DomainController.Instance.GetWord("BijsluiterTitle");
    private View view;
    private WebView webview;
    private string url;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.BijsluiterFragment, container, false);
        webview = view.FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webView);
        webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled=true;
        webview.Settings.SetPluginState (WebSettings.PluginState.On);
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            webview.LoadUrl ("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void SetUrl(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

I also tried with the 'loadwithbaseurl' method but it didn't work either...

Comment: This is the same question asked in thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139837/webview-will-not-load-pdf-files-on-link-click

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same problem with this:

```
if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
    try {
         String urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
         url = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + urlEncoded;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With this prefix: "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" the WebView open the pdf with GoogleDocs.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: nope didn't work, i get "[AwContents] nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color".