# How to detect when redirects in WebView finish?

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I have gone through every related post I found here and still can't get it to work.
I'm opening my WebView with a URL that has redirects (sometimes many redirects) and I want to know when the loading is really finished (URL finished loading with no more redirects).

So any suggestions?

Every post I read said to override shouldOverrideUrlLoading but no matter what I do shouldOverrideUrlLoading does not get called.

My code:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
mUrl = "http://cdn.something.com/something.html";
//    mUrl = "https://www.google.com";
mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);



public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public MyWebViewClient() {}

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClient: shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClient: onPageStarted:  url: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClient: onPageFinished: url: " + url);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try onLoadResource method?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659000/java-how-to-find-the-redirected-url-of-a-url) answer.. and you have to check if url redirect done or not in `onPageStarted` method of `WebViewClient`...

Comment: @555 **never** edit source code just because you think "URL" should be in capital letters as **THAT BREAKS THE PROGRAM**. Please *stop* making questions worse by editing, especially if you're not perfect with the programming languages involved. *You're actively harming this community*.

Answer (score 3):

you are overriding the new `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method which was added in `android N`,

you have to override both methods to make it work (old one which is deprecated and new one)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    return handleUri(uri);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
    return handleUri(uri);
}
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484061/6478047)
 ,and `onPageFinished` will be called when page has finished loading

Comment: Thank you, this got shouldOverrideUrlLoading to fire, now I'll try using it to implement the suggestions i found.
onPageFinished is called many times, my problem is finding out which is definitely the last time it is called.

Comment: Also I want the redirects to be handled within the webview so the handleUri method is no good for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case WebViewClient wasn't showing if there was changes on the webview, I supposed that is something about the web that is been running.

I could get that information from the WebChromeClient with OnProgressChanged, I don't know if this would help people anyway, but here is the code:

```
webview.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){

        override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)

            if (newProgress == 100) {
                Log.d("testing", webview.getOriginalUrl())
                Log.d("testing", webview.url)
            }
        }
    }
```

This way I could know what is been loaded and when is finished.