# Android Open HTML file on web view Android Nougat (7.0)

Tags: android, html, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to open a html file (from the assets folder) and displaying it into a Webview. That works. My Problem is, the HTML has a hyperlink and I cannot get the right URL to rich the second HTML file I want to open.

Could someone help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36484720/3278010

Comment: No we cannot help you if you do not show your html source with the link.

Answer (score 0):

My html file in the assets has a line like "<"a href="./file2.html"">" Back"<"/a">" (file2 is as well in the assets folder)

File infoFile = StoringFileUtil.getInfoFile(this, fileName);

infoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "PROVIDER_PACKAGE_NAME", infoFile); 
after that I set the webview passing the Uri infoWebView.loadUrl(infoURI.toString());