# shouldOverrideUrlLoading is Deprecated, is @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") a solution?

Tags: android, url, webview

In Android Studio I get this warning `shouldOverrideUrlLoading is Deprecated` if I add this line `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` I dont get anymore the warning but is it correct to do that? This is the code I use

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,  String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484720/2215962) CommonsWare answer.

But, in any way, use `@SuppressWarnings` isn't a solution.

Comment: That helped a lot Volodymyr I followed the advice from the answer you gave me and it worked, only thing i changed after I used the  `WebResourceRequest request` was the `minSdkVersion` in gradle from 19 to 21 cause the `request.getUrl` asked for a different api.

Comment: @Zoel In that case users with devices with Android lower than Lollipop will not be able to install your application. In that case, you have to implement something
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            //deprecated method
        } else {
            //new method
        }

Comment: Thank you @Volodymyr-Yatsykiv, I noticed that too, I appreciate your help.