# The Function shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not working in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview to load website.
Website is loading properly. When i click on any link it redirects to mobile browser. So i searched on internet and used the function

```js
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  private boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView myWebView, WebResourseRequest request) {

    myWebView.loadUrl(request.toString());
    return true;
  }

});
```

Here WebResourseRequest  and toString is not resolved. It saying cannot resolve symbol. How to solve it? Do i need to Import anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
 });
```

Change the parameters like this.
Instead of `WebResourseRequest` use `String`

Comment: if i use this structure, shouldOverrideUrlLoading is deprecated  method in android.webkit message is coming and shouldOverrideUrlLoading  not working.

Comment: WebResourseRequest  added in N Developer Preview. You have to update the library. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484720/2610010

Comment: How to use the function you had given? is there any solution to make it work?

Comment: The code given will work even though it is deprecated