# WebViewClient shouldOverrideUrlLoading doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to listen to url changes from a WebView client and just log the updates. I'm navigating through my webView and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is never called. I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String url= i.getStringExtra("url");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                String currentUrl = url;
                Log.i("currentUrl",": " + currentUrl);
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484074/is-shouldoverrideurlloading-really-deprecated-what-can-i-use-instead

Comment: I didn't find any answer to my issue in this thread.

Comment: The answers clearly show that there are two methods you have to implement, you have only implemented the old deprecated method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Comment: I tried to implement the two methods, then one at a time, neither one was logging something to the console.

Comment: It seems that the boolean is working well though. I wonder why my Log function isn't working.